# EF Core 2 context empty in webapi integration tests

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

After migrate to EF Core 2.0 (from 1.1) my integration tests failing, because context created by DI is empty.

My Startup in WebApp.Tests assembly:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(x => x.UseInMemoryDatabase(nameof(MyContext))
                .ConfigureWarnings(z => z.Ignore(InMemoryEventId.TransactionIgnoredWarning))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging());
```

My IntegartionTestFixture class contains

```
var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseContentRoot(contentRoot)
            .ConfigureServices(OverrideServices)
            .UseEnvironment("Development")
            .UseStartup(typeof(WebApp.Tests.Startup))
            ;

        _server = new TestServer(builder);

        Client = _server.CreateClient();
```

My tests started with

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(nameof(MyContext))
            .Options;
using (var db = new MyContext(options))
        {
            db.SeedSingleUserLogin();
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Later I make call to webapi, and dbcontext injected into my controller is empty.

Comment: What does "is empty" mean? That it has no data? That it has no DbSet properties?

Comment: no data of course

Comment: Well, I don't see any data loading method. However, it could be that you should get the context from the ServiceContainer rather than creating an instance

Comment: Than why it is work before migration? I as far as I understand, `UseInMemoryDatabase(string)` with same `string` should fallback to EF core 1.* behaviour